# Hypothesis Matrix and Eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a matrix $A=$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & -1 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 & -2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$ and I want to show that the columns of this matrix are the eigenvectors of $HH'$, where $H$ is the hypothesis matrix, and then find the associated eigenvalues.

My attempt: I wanted to use this form of the hypothesis matrix:

$H$=sum of squares matrix=$I_{k-1}|\frac{1}{k}J_{k-1}{J_k}'$
Because $A$ is a 3x3 matrix, $k$ would equal 4 I think. $J$ is a vector of 1's. I just don't know how to get from here to the eigenvectors/eigenvalues.